# Where in an Android application's project tree to put developers' documentation?

Tags: android, documentation

I developed an Android application.

In addition to comments in source files, I wrote also roadmap type documentation, intended to help other developers understand the overall application's structure.

My question:
Where in the project tree to put the documentation files, so that they'll be available to developers duplicating the project tree, but not packaged into the installation APK files?

Comment: `doc/` would seem logical.

Answer (score 2):

Common pracice is to include a top-level `README` or `README.md` (markdown) that contains the high-level documentation. This file is placed in the project root directory.

Many project hosting providers such as GitHub render this README file when viewing the project on the website.

For detailed documentation, keep using the inline javadoc.